# Restore previous state of a git repository as a whole?

Tags: git

During cleanup I frequently have to do major rebase operations. Reword this commit, reorder those commits, merge a few, ...

And in this, things can go wrong. In principle this can be easily solved (`git branch tmp` before any operations, or looking up the old heads in `reflog`), but it is tedious.

Is there some kind of repository-level "Undo" facility in git, that allows restoring a previous state of the repository? I.e. *not* restoring the *files* to a specific commit, but something like restoring a previous state of `./.git/refs/`.

Comment: Maybe just work on a clone? or keep a clone as a backup?

Comment: @RomainValeri This is possible, but more effort than the `git branch temp` variant. It is more about making "Undo" easier in case I didn't expect the problems ahead of time.

Comment: I'd use `git branch tmp && git worktree add /path/to/foo tmp` to create a working tree for `tmp`. If everything goes smoothly, the result is stored in `.git` of the main working tree. If it's messed up, just run `git worktree remove /path/to/foo` as if nothing has happened.

Comment: First : it looks like you already are pretty close to a no sweat "undo" setup.

Comment: I usually start with `git chekcout -b temp`. If things go south, the only ref that got modified is that `temp` ref. @ElpieKay has a good suggestion : you can additionally run things in a separate directory on disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a snapshot of all your local refs, simply run `git for-each-ref`.

The default output format will already print a usable format :

```
$ git for-each-ref
0eab2ed387d26494897ec86c6e94e309398dfde9 commit refs/heads/foobar
2184668f46fd19bc3dca183941cc1c177ea3f067 commit refs/heads/master
7f5989b4749ba31c0249d364db27115ddbfd1396 commit refs/tags/good
f79b1a4d27b88ab93b725b250ceb3a8440fd40f3 commit refs/tags/bad
```

You can tweak the output with the `--format` option if you want.

You can limit this to local branches and tags, and store it in a file :

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/tags > ../repo-snapshot.txt
```

You can then compare your current state with that snapshot at any time :

```
diff ../repo-snapshot.txt <(git for-each-ref refs/heads refs/tags)
```